# Setting A dependency property by this

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, controls, dependency-properties

I've created a type of Border called SelectableBorder that has an additional property called "IsSelected". I'm using this property in some triggers e.g.:

```
<MultiTrigger.Conditions>
 <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
 <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
</MultiTrigger.Conditions>
<MultiTrigger.Setters>
 <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush3}" />
</MultiTrigger.Setters>
```

However in the code in the background there is no way for me to set IsSelected, How do I go about creating a property that can be used in xaml triggers and in code in the background?

This is the current SelectableBorder code

```
public class SelectableBorder : Border
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsSelectedProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsSelected", typeof(bool), typeof(Border), new PropertyMetadata(false));

    public static void SetIsSelected(UIElement element, bool value)
    {
        element.SetValue(IsSelectedProperty, value);
    }

    public static bool GetIsSelected(UIElement element)
    {
        return (bool)element.GetValue(IsSelectedProperty);
    }
}
```

I am also seeing:

'SelectableBorder' initialization failed: The type initializer for 'SelectableBorder' threw an exception.

Which suggests to me that I'm not doing that well at my first attempt. Could you please guide me in the correct direction to solving these problems?

Comment: Did you try `Register` instead of `RegisterAttached`?

Comment: Yep, seeing the same exception error and 'SelectableBorder' does not contain a definition for 'IsSelected' and no extension method 'IsSelected' accepting a first argument of type 'SelectableBorder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)

Comment: owner type should be `SelectableBorder` and not `Border`

Comment: That fixed it the exception, however unable to set it in the background code

Comment: how do you set it? do you use your `SetIsSelected` method?

Comment: I've sussed it! If you add the owner type comment as the answer i'll mark it. Many thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're adding property to `DependencyObject` so you can use normal `DependencyProperty` instead of attached one. You can use attached if you want but then trigger should change. Also owner type of your property should be `SelectableBorder` instead of `Border`. You can also add `IsSelected` CLR wrapper do make it easier to set/get value in code behind.

```
public class SelectableBorder : Border
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsSelectedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsSelected", typeof(bool), typeof(SelectableBorder), new PropertyMetadata(false));

    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsSelectedProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsSelectedProperty, value); }
    }
}
```